# IOS/Cordova Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path

Tags: xcode, cordova, app-store-connect

I am trying to publish my app on the app store but I get this  error. I have no idea where it is coming from. My certifications and signing are managed automaticaly by XCode. (Select is empty because I erased it on the screenshot)

[image]

> Invalid Signature - A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file
>   at path [AlphaBane.app/AlphaBane] is not properly signed. Make sure
>   you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not
>   an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the
>   code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which
>   override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the
>   bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode,
>   not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings
>   are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory
>   in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information,
>   please consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

I started a brand new project with Cordova, and I am still facing this error. As Always, Apple error are self-explained (irony). What do I have to do to fix this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing the same thing in a project (on Xcode 9.2) with multiple targets (different version of a single app framework) - all targets pass except one. One of my apps continued to get this error. Perfect situation to look into why this is happening. I first thought it was the signature profile (development vs distribution certificate). Check that first.

But in my case, I had a few files that were not being used by the code that I had excluded from the build. When I added these resources my build passed. Check to see that all needed resources are included in the File Inspector panel. This includes code and media resources.

[image: Target membership]

Comment: also make sure that none of your files have any characters other than alpha-numerical - I had an accent in a media file and it threw the same error.

Comment: Thks for your answer! What do you mean by "few swift files" as my project is a cordova's?

Comment: any media files with bad form will also throw this error.